# Get the name of the Background Service Class that is hosting a DI class

Tags: asp.net-core, background-service

Good day all.

I have an asp.net core solution (NopCommerce 4.4) where I'm registering multiple classes that inherit from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService.  These are using Dependency Injection to get access to several other classes at runtime.

Some of these DI classes need to know which specific class (derived from BackgroundService) they were instantiated in so they can return data specific to the background service that's "hosting" them.  For example, each Background Service has it's own ECommerce Store it's responsible for processing data in.

How can I determine what Hosted Service is the "context" for the DI classes that it is requiring?

Comment: Can you create a simple sample to explain your question?

Comment: The main problem is that i can't figure out how to write the code I need, so I'm not sure what example to provide.  I guess what I want is some sort of function I can call to know what IHostedService instance is responsible for Instantiating an injected class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As I said above, there is no problem to reproduce.  No Errors, no functionality that I wrote that doesn't work, no code that's "broken".  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to achieve a technical goal.  Perhaps this isn't an appropriate forum for discussing ideas and concepts, but i figured it was worth a try.  If I have time, I can try to create some code to post, just so there's something to look at... but I don't see what value it will provide, since it will be devoid of what I need it to do.